# Style Commponent, Typescript, flex-box, flexbox not displaying correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, flexbox

I have a StackBlitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jefhjh?file=App.tsx,styled.ts

It's a simple react app with Typescript

I have a style component that uses flex-box to position two columbns next to each other.

I'm passing the widths of the columns into the wrapping container like `<FlexContainer width={['60%', '40%']}>`

And then using the values in the component like

```
export const FlexContainer = styled.div<IProps>`
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex:
  // align-content: stretch;

  .divOne{
    border: 2px solid pink;
    height: 500px;
    width: ${(p) => p.width[0]};
  }

  .divTwo{
    border: 2px solid green;
    height: 500px;
    width: ${(p) => p.width[1]};
  }

`;
```

Only one the second column is being displayed.

I know the first column is getting a value because if I use `align-content: stretch` the first column displays but the layout is wrong.

I'm sure the mistake the way I'm using flex-box

How can I get the layout to work ?

Comment: Personally this seems a bit too convoluted and highly dependent on using not only two elements ONLY inside of the FlexContainer, but also using the correct classes.  Can you use CSS grid?  You can fix this easily with grid in three lines and safely have any number of children display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a colon instead of a semicolon. Use `display: flex;` instead of `display:flex:`. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-quu5ce?file=App.tsx,styled.ts

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface IProps {
  width?: string[];
}

export const FlexContainer = styled.div<IProps>`
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;

  .divOne{
    border: 2px solid pink;
    height: 500px;
    width: ${(p) => p.width[0]};
  }

  .divTwo{
    border: 2px solid green;
    height: 500px;
    width: ${(p) => p.width[1]};
  }
`;
```